# html returns as xml when calling webservice (asmx) in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asmx

I have a jquery block that does some ajax stuff like this:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: '/webservices/manager.asmx/addNew',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    data: { id: Id, name: Name, dept: Dept, helpId: HelpId },
    success: function (data) {
        //append to the table
        $('#divManagers').append(data); 
    },
    error: function () {
        //console.log('error');
    }
});
```

So it passes through just fine, asmx receives the data and I calculate stuff, then finally I respond with something similar to this:

```
<div id="divContainer">
         <h2>Manager Name</h2>
</div>
```

Now, even though I have my `dataType` set to `html` I get my response encased in an xml string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">&lt;div id=divContainer&gt;&lt;/h4&gt;Manager&nbsp;Name&lt;/div&gt;</string>
```

and they all actually just gets appended to the page, the complete text, without rendering as actual html elements.

What is going on please?

**EDIT**

I am just constructing the html in my asmx. something like

```
StringBuilder component = new StringBuilder();
component.appendFormat("<div id='divComponent'><h2>{0}</h2></div>', managerDataRow["ManagerName"].ToString());
return component.ToString();
```

My asmx is a seperate, proper asmx page, not a [webmethod] method inside a normal aspx page. Thanks.

---

<sup>if there are any difference between my actual output and returned result **here** it is because I edited it to make it short. thanks.</sup>

Comment: can you share your service code?

Comment: I would first recommend to check the actual data and its content type that your server is returning (using Fiddler or similar tools)

Comment: @Evgeny, well, i have included the response I am getting from the service here, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create a jQuery object from the response and read the `text` value from there to get the desired result.

```
$('#divManagers').append($(data).text());
```

---

Also this post might answer why you don't get back straight HTML in the response

[How to get clean/pure HTML from ASMX web service call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919243/how-to-get-clean-pure-html-from-asmx-web-service-call)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set webResponse `ContentType` to: `"text/html"`

**EDITED:**

But anyway you can return `JSON` or `XML` and grab your data (XML using xpath, JSON just js object) and buid your div on the client site (you have better control on what you printing). Service should only provide **plain data** without any html stuff..

Comment: According to the link you provided there is!

Comment: HA! in the link that you posted, it does say html!

Comment: Sorry :) there is i'am just to tired :/

Comment: I am not using a page for webresponse?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the C# asmx code please?

You may have set the `ContentType` in the response like so:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
```

Or make sure you set the return type.  For example, my service:

```
[WebService]
public class MySvc : WebService {

    [WebMethod (Description="Proxy for MyService")]
    public String Proxy()
    {return "<h1>MyHeader</h1>"}
}
```

More on SO w/ jQuery and ASMX:
[Calling ASMX from jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879362/calling-asmx-from-jquery)

Comment: Hi, sorry but that did not really work, i am going throught the link you posted, thanks.